# How to display data corresponding to 2 coulms into a third and fourth column in SQL within a sigle table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying to have a nested query where i can select and display The build Id's of different artifats corresponding to environments selected. Here is the schema.

```
Environment Name  Artifact Name     Build Id    
UAT 2           aecacs.ear          147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-243    
UAT 2           gbcr.ear            147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-244    
UAT 2           esms.ear            147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-23    
UAT 2           framework.ear       147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-156    
SIT 2           ecr.ear             147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-198    
SIT 2           aecacs.ear          147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-33    
SIT 2           gbcr.ear            147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-56    
SIT 2           ci.ear              147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-87    
SIT 2           co.ear              147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-22    
DIT 2           aecacs.ear          147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-158    
DIT 2           esms.ear    
DIT 2           build.ear
```

I want All artifact Names to be listed in the first colums.

In second coulmn the 'Build Id' corresponding to environment UAT2A and that artifact

In the third coulmn Build Id corresponding to that artifact and environment SIT2.

If a build Id doesnt exist corresponding to an environment and Artifact name it should say "Not Found"

OUTPUT:

```
ARTIFCAT NAME         BUILD ID(UAT 2)                              BUILD ID (SIT 1)

aecacs.ear        147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-243  147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-33

gbcr.ear          147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-244  147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-56

esms.ear          147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-23   not found

framework.ear

ecr.ear

ci.ear

co.ear
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is with two left outer self joins.

Use Coalesce to display not found when the build_id was not found.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name, COALESCE(a1.build_id,'Not Found'), COALESCE(a2.buildId,'Not Found')
FROM Artifact a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Artifact a1 ON a1.Name = a.Name
LEFT OUTER JOIN Artifact a2 ON a2.Name = a.Name
WHERE a1.Environment = 'UAT 2'
AND a2.Environment = 'SIT 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Pivot function if your Oracle version is 11g +

Query :

```
with Artifact (Environment_Name, Artifact_Name, Build_Id) as (
select 'UAT 2', 'aecacs.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-243' from dual union all
select 'UAT 2', 'gbcr.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-244' from dual union all
select 'UAT 2', 'esms.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-23' from dual union all
select 'UAT 2', 'framework.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-156' from dual union all
select 'SIT 2', 'ecr.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-198' from dual union all
select 'SIT 2', 'aecacs.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-33' from dual union all
select 'SIT 2', 'gbcr.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-56' from dual union all
select 'SIT 2', 'ci.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-87' from dual union all
select 'SIT 2', 'co.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-22' from dual union all
select 'DIT 2', 'aecacs.ear', '147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-158' from dual union all
select 'DIT 2', 'esms.ear', '' from dual union all
select 'DIT 2', 'build.ear', '' from dual)

------------
----End of data preparation
------------
select artifact_name, coalesce(UAT2, 'Not Found') as UAT2, coalesce(SIT2, 'Not Found') as SIT2
  from Artifact
 pivot (min(Build_Id) for environment_name in ('UAT 2' as UAT2, 'SIT 2' as SIT2));
```

Output

```
| ARTIFACT_NAME |                                 UAT2 |                                 SIT2 |
|---------------|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|
|      esms.ear |  147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-23 |                            Not Found |
|    aecacs.ear | 147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-243 |  147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-33 |
|      gbcr.ear | 147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-244 |  147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-56 |
| framework.ear | 147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-156 |                            Not Found |
|        co.ear |                            Not Found |  147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-22 |
|       ecr.ear |                            Not Found | 147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-198 |
|        ci.ear |                            Not Found |  147634-CBOL-9.0.1-APP-Team-Build-87 |
|     build.ear |                            Not Found |                            Not Found |
```

Your query will be:

```
select artifact_name, coalesce(UAT2, 'Not Found') as UAT2, coalesce(SIT2, 'Not Found') as SIT2
  from Artifact 
 pivot (min(Build_Id) for environment_name in ('UAT 2' as UAT2, 'SIT 2' as SIT2));
```

Comment: We dont have oracle 11g+.Got to write the query in a Java util class to connect to DB through DAO class for a web based application.